# JS passing value and choose return var

Tags: javascript

It is possible to return only 1 value from function witch returning 5 values?
Example include only 2 values:

```js
   function checkNum(x){
    if(x>0){
       if(x>59){
           return "green" , "pass";
       }
       else{
           return "red" , "try again";
       }
    }
    else{
        return "yellow","play the game";
    }
    }

    console.log(checkNum(33));
```

As you see it only return 2nd val witch is try again...

How get something like that:  Sorry "try again" you are "red"!!

or i have to copy each function and change names for each return state??

Please give a clue.

Comment: You can only return 1 value from a function - you'd need to put your elements in an array or some structure and return that if you want multiple values returned from your function.

Comment: Use an array `["green","pass"]` or object `{color:"green",message:"pass"}`.

Comment: Slightly off topic but could be useful here: If you return an array, you can pass that value as multiple arguments like this: `console.log(...checkNum(x))` (that is a literal three periods (`...`), sometimes called a splat operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning an array is probably what you want:

```
function checkNum(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    if (x > 59) {
      return ["green", "pass"];
    } else {
      return ["red", "try again"];
    }
  } else {
    return ["yellow", "play the game"];
  }
}

const [color, message] = checkNum(33);
console.log(`${color} - ${message}`);
```

You could also return an object if you prefer:

```
function checkNum(x) {
  if (x > 0) {
    if (x > 59) {
      return { color: "green" , message: "pass" };
    } else {
      return { color: "red" , message: "try again" };
    }
  } else {
    return { color: "yellow", message: "play the game" };
  }
}

const { color, message } = checkNum(33);
console.log(`${color} - ${message}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do what you have in mind, you can for example create a string and return it like so :

```
   function checkNum(x){
    if(x>0){
      ...
       else{
           return 'Try again, ' + 'you are red !!!'
       }
    }
    ...
    }
```

Also, keep in mind that you can only return one value from a function, and when you are returning like what you did a lot of values or any other javascript expression, only the most right-handed expression will be the return value.

```
function aLotOfReturn() {
    return 'one', 1 + 2, {}, 'four';
}
aLotOfReturn() // returns 'four'
```

if you want to return multiple values you can use different type of primitives that fits those needs like : [key-value object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) or [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

like so

```
function returnMultipleColors() {
    return ['blue', 'red', 'yellow'];
}

let colors = returnMultipleColors();
```

You have now an array of colors, you can choose to iterate over it using the .forEach method or [many more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) to do whatever you want with each value.

**UPDATE** : here is an article illustrating some useful javascript array and object methods : https://codeburst.io/useful-javascript-array-and-object-methods-6c7971d93230